# Add icons to VSCode tree view

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to set icons to the tree view but it's not working. Here is my code :

```
export class MyClass extends vscode.TreeItem {
    constructor(
    public readonly label: string,
    private version: string,
    public readonly collapsibleState: vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState,
    public readonly command?: vscode.Command) 
    {
      super(label, collapsibleState);
    }

 get tooltip(): string {
        return `tooltip works`;
    }

  iconPath = {
        light: path.join(__filename, '..', 'resources', 'light', 'dependency.svg'),
        dark: path.join(__filename, '..', 'resources', 'dark', 'dependency.svg')
    };
}
```

Is there anything else I need to configure?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Had the exact same issue, add another `'..'` to your path join.

```
iconPath = {
        light: path.join(__filename, '..', '..', 'resources', 'light', 'dependency.svg'),
        dark: path.join(__filename, '..', '..', 'resources', 'dark', 'dependency.svg')
    };
```

This is because all the paths are referenced from the `out/` directory so you need to go up 1 more to reach your resources.

Comment: Thanks. It works.  "All the paths are referenced from the out directory" exactly explains why It was not working.